# Function call via the button

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote the code to send the email to node.js and they are in different files:

**mail.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.mail.ru',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
  },
})

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'Mailer Test <>',
    to: '<>',
    subject: ''
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

and button:

**script.js**

```
let submitButton = document.querySelector('.submit_button');
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
})
```

how do I call execution in the buttons mail.js?

Comment: You will have to set up a node.js route that does that and send a request to it from the browser when the user clicks the button. How are you serving your HTML?

Comment: @ Jared Smith Not quite understood about the service

Comment: You need to call the backend code. You need a form submission or ajax/fetch request.

Comment: You (and I'm not trying to be rude, we all start *somewhere*) need to work through some basic tutorials about how the web works. There isn't a simple straightforward answer to your question that doesn't depend on a bunch of stuff that you appear to not know.

Comment: For instance, glancing at [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72391582/sending-the-results-of-the-quiz-by-email) you were trying to do the same thing in PHP. So you were almost certainly serving/routing via apache and would need a separate PHP page to handle the request from the client. Node (and everything else that isn't PHP) works differently. You could use Apache to serve static files and have a node.js server running that you called out to with AJAX. That should at least give you a starting point for some google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mail.js is executed in a server environment, where the client (the browser) cannot access it. Your script.js is probably running on an HTML page. The frontend (browser) cannot directly access the backend.

I recommend setting up an [Express](https://expressjs.com) server with a route to send the mail.

Download the express (and body-parser) package:

```
npm install express body-parser

# or

yarn add express body-parser
```

Make a file called `index.js`, and set up a basic express server:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Body parser allows you to parse data from the body, or from a URL, like function parameters.

Next, we tell the app to listen for connections on port `3000`. The app will wait until a connection is received and then decide what to do next.

Now, we can add a route. A route is an endpoint, or a location in a URL
For example:
`https://google.com/search` would be the `/search` route
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234` would be the `/questions/1234` route

We'll add the `/mail` route, and take in two parameters: `to`, and `subject`. Your client will specify this when the request is sent.

Then, we'll execute the `mail` function that will be your `mail.js` code.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config()
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

function mail(to, subject) {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.mail.ru',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'Mailer Test <>',
        to: to,
        subject: subject
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/mail', (req, res) => { // The req variable is the request, or the data, and the res variable is the response that you send back.
    const query = req.query; // The URL encoded data that your HTML page will send
    const to = query.to; // you will specify these in the HTML page
    const subject = query.subject;

    mail(to, subject);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Use `node index.js` to start your server.

Now, in your `script.js`, you can send an [ajax request](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20request&rlz=1CAEOEW_enUS982&oq=ajax%20request&aqs=chrome.0.0i131i433i512j0i512l9.1033j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#:%7E:text=What%20exactly%20is,what%2Dexactly%2Dis%2D...) to the URL: `localhost:3000/mail?to=test@gmail.com&subject=Subject!`

Happy coding!